# Hot Module (HMR) doesnt work when config ModuleFederation, vue-cli@5.0.0-rc.0

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli, webpack-module-federation

I was looking into Webpack 5 Module federation feature, fortunately, it works in my project, but I have some trouble understanding why my Hot Module Replacement(HMR) does not work, errors:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting './node_modules/@vue/cli-plugin-babel/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-40[0].rules[0].use[0]!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ruleSet[0].rules[0].use[0]!./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/node_modules/@vue/vue-loader-v15/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./src/layout/components/NavBar.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&')
    at webpackHotUpdatevue2_cli5 (remoteEntry.js:2884)
    at app.5c4dd6501efc06e4.hot-update.js:10
```

I feel so helpless. I'm using @vue/cli@5.0.0-rc.0. The vue.config.js which exposes its modules looks like below,

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: 'http://localhost:8084/',
  chainWebpack: (config) => {
    config
      .plugin('module-federation-plugin')
      .use(require('webpack').container.ModuleFederationPlugin, [{
        name: "home",
        filename: "remoteEntry.js",
        exposes: {
          './HelloWorld': './src/components/HelloWorld.vue'
        },
        shared: {
          vuex: {
            eager: true,
            singleton: true,
          },
        },
    }])
  },

  devServer: {
    port: 8084,
    hot: true,
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, PATCH, OPTIONS",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers":
        "X-Requested-With, content-type, Authorization",
    }
  }
}
```